# Missing file error in GeoIP after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: ruby, homebrew, geoip

I was fixing and cleaning up Homebrew after upgrading to OS X El Capitan. When I was testing my "cellar" downloads, I found that `geoip` outputs this:

```
John-iMac:~ John$ geoip
/Users/John/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/geoip-1.5.0/lib/geoip.rb:235:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/John/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/geoip-1.5.0/lib/geoip.rb:235:in `open'
    from /Users/John/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/geoip-1.5.0/lib/geoip.rb:235:in `initialize'
    from /Users/John/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/geoip-1.5.0/bin/geoip:11:in `new'
    from /Users/John/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/geoip-1.5.0/bin/geoip:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/geoip:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/geoip:23:in `<main>'
```

I've tried `brew doctor` and it says that everything's fine. I've also reinstalled `geoip` and `brew unlink geoip && brew link geoip` but that doesn't fix it either. Any ideas for a fix please?

Comment: Does the file /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat excist? Wat are the read rights on the file?

Comment: Nope, not on my system

Answer (score 0):

Check the second answer of this post https://superuser.com/questions/303460/is-there-a-way-to-install-geoip-from-source-code-on-mac-os-x especially the part saying "Installing GeoIP databases"